# Safely escape out String before EVAL()

Tags: php, security, code-injection

So what I want to do is as follows

There will be an external config file that contains

```
RunCommand = "SomePHPCommand($SomeVariable)"
```

But the config file

```
$SomeVariable = GetFromWebCall();  //Obtained Externally, needs to be made safe

$PHPCommand = LoadFromConfig(RunCommand)  //Obtained externally but safe controlled environment.  No clean necessary

result = eval($PHPCommand)
```

In short, the config file is SAFE.  But the $SomeVariable could contain something malicious and I need to plan for that.

How do I safely escape out the $SomeVariable before running my eval command?

Comment: `eval` can usually be replaced by something more secure. Is there a particular reason why the command has to be obtained externally? Could you not have a keyword obtained externally that could be "mapped" to a particular command? What kind of commands are you expecting?

Comment: There's no general way to clean the variable. There's no way to tell what's malicious and what isn't.

Comment: What is "safe" in your case?

Comment: If you want security, you want a whitelist of what's allowed. If you can fill in a bit of info on what types of user input you expect from `GetFromWebCall`, we might have ideas on how to implement it safely.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to make a variable safe. But you can allow or disallow specific commands.

```php
function isSafe($command){
    //checking for some Program execution Functions
    $isMalicious = preg_match("/(?:passthru\(.*\))|(?:exec\(.*\))|(?:system\(.?\))/",$command);
    if($isMalicious === 1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Before executing the command you can do the following:

```php
$safe = isSafe($PHPCommand);
if($safe){
    eval($PHPCommand);
}else{
    echo("Command not safe!");
}
```

All Program execution Functions [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php).